# How to distinguish between linux original commands and third-party software commands

Tags: node.js, linux

My teacher wanted me to implement the function of calling the shell commands using nodejs and expected to print executable path when calling third-part software commands.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');
function execute(cmd) {
            if(not linux original command) cmd='whereis '+cmd  
            exec(cmd, {encoding: 'buffer'}, (error, stdout) => {
                if(error) console.log(error);;
                console.log(iconv.decode(stdout,'gbk'))
            });
}
execute("ls -l");  //  the result is 'drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 ...'
execute("node") // the result is 'usr/local/node'
```

Comment: Whats a "original" command? Those are all just executables.

Comment: @tkausl Commands that can be executed without installation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what commands are built-in in the kernel, maybe this can help you (using the `which` command):

```
> which -a which
which: shell built-in command
/usr/bin/which
> which -a find
/usr/bin/find
```

The `type` command also works:

```
> type -a which
which is a shell builtin
which is /usr/bin/which

> type -a cd
cd is an alias for __enhancd::cd
cd is a shell builtin
cd is /usr/bin/cd

> type -a ls
ls is an alias for ls -G
ls is /bin/ls
```